# How to call a function [do something] after a UIAlertAction?

Tags: ios, swift, action, uialertaction

I have created a class which allows me to customize a UIAlertAction whenever I need. The problem is that I need to do something, call a function which is inside another class, after the user presses delete (the option other than cancel)

What I tried:

```
let dAction = ActionButtonOptions(isReportButton: false, selectedPost: selectedPost!, numberMedia: numberMedia, forP3: true) 
self.present(dAction.action, animated: true, completion: {
       if dAction.hasDeleted {
                print("83908120938292180918309123 ", dAction.hasDeleted)
                self.nextGestureMethods()//these two things are teh things I need to do
                self.selectedPost?.interimMedia.remove(at: self.numberMedia-1)
            } else {
                print("837vgvgvgvgvgvgvgv908120938292180918309123", dAction.hasDeleted)
            }
})
```

**Update**: I believe the code above does not work because teh completion runs after the presenting is complete not when the user finished interacting with the popup.

inside of that other class: if the user presses the delete button I make the hasDeleted variable true. The problem is that the code in the completion seems to just go strait to the else.

**How can I accomplish what I am intending?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the alert controller add thie var

```
var callback:((Bool)->())?
```

and when action happens inside handler of delete do

```
callback?(true/false)
```

and to listen

```
dAction.callback = { [weak self] (value) in 
   print(value)
}
```